# Flask not rendering html

Tags: python, html, flask

This is the code read but Flask not rendering html

```
 from flask import Flask,render_template
 import psycopg2
 import psycopg2.extras

 app=Flask(__name__)

 app.route('/')
 def index():
      return render_template('index.html')

 if __name__=="__main__":
     app.run(debug=True, port=9001)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, it's just a typo error. Supposed you already have a file called `index.html` in your `templates` folder. So your tree look like this:

```
.
└── my_app/
    ├── templates/
    │   └── index.html
    └── run.py
```

This code should work:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') # <-- You are missing the '@' here
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__": # <-- Note this too
    app.run(debug=True, port=9001)
```

Now you can access to your project at http://127.0.0.1:9001/

To learn more about Flask view decorator, go [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/viewdecorators/).

For more information about what mean `if __name__ == "__main__":`, you can read more [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-name-main-python-example/).